Duplicated data from firestore flutter
I tried to fetch data from firebase firestore without streams to handle changes with FutureBuilder, but I got duplicated data like username, profile pic, when I use it inside listView everything fine, I tried a lot to figure out the problem.

Methods:
Future? getBusinessListFuture;

  Future<void> fetchMessages() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chatRooms').where("participantIDs", arrayContains: auth.currentUser!.uid).get();

    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      List<String> fullData = data['participants'].keys.toList();
      fullData.remove(auth.currentUser!.uid);
      getBusinessListFuture = FirebaseHelper.getUserModelById(fullData[0]);
    });
    setState(() {});
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    fetchMessages();
    super.initState();
  }

UI:
FutureBuilder(
  future: getBusinessListFuture,
  builder: (context, userData) {
    if (userData.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      if (userData.data != null) {
        ControllerModel targetUser =
        userData.data as ControllerModel;    
                                ......


FirebaseHelper Class:
static Future<ControllerModel?> getUserModelById(String uid) async {

  ControllerModel? userModel;

  try{
    DocumentSnapshot docSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(uid).get();
    if(docSnap.data() != null) {
      userModel = ControllerModel.fromMap(docSnap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
    }

  }catch(e){
    print('$e (Firebase_helper)');
  }
  return userModel;

}

Thanks.
